# Can we solve an exact ordinary differential equation of first degree and order using linear differential equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

Can we solve differential equations $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ using linear algebra or any method of reducing it into a linear differential equation and hence solve it or do we nee any multivariable analysis concept here?By the way what is the domain of values of $x,y$ here?
What is the meaning of the differential equation?I think it means solve for $y=g(x)$ such that $y$ satisfies the equation.But the the question is what is the domain of $g$ ?

Comment: Linear algebra is **not** a tool for making non-linear things linear.

Comment: So how to approach to solve it?

Comment: @IvanNeretin do I require multivariable calculus for this?

Comment: It depends on $f$. You know this thing is called an _ordinary differential equation_, and you likely know there are whole _books_ on this subject. That's how broad is your question. What kind of an answer would you expect? _"Throw out all them books, it is solved in a such-and-such way"_? No, it doesn't work like that.